# Finding the inverse of 84 mod 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I did:

$$gcd(84,5) = \\
84 = 5*16+4 \\
5=4*1+1$$

$$4 = 84-5*16 \\
1 = 5-4*1 \\
1 = 5-(84-5*16)\\
1 = 17*5-1*84$$

So the answer should be $1$ but it's 4, what went wrong?

Comment: It’s $-1,$ which is $4\pmod5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1 = 17\cdot 5-1\cdot 84 = 17\cdot 5+(-1)\cdot 84$ tells us that the answer is $-1$, which is the same as $4$, mod $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $84=4$ mod $5$. Thus $84 \times4=4\times4 $ mod $5$. Thus $84 \times4=16=1 $ mod $5$. Thus $4 $ mod $5$ is the inverse.