# Find the inverse of 105 mod 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I did:

$$105 = 4*26+1\\
1 = 105*1-4*26$$

So the inverse should be 5 as it is $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ but it's 1. Why?

Comment: This is quite similar to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433860

Comment: @MartinR This one is slightly different

Comment: I'm curious why you chose $5,$ since I do not see it anywhere in your equations. Why didn't you choose $1,$ which is in the equation? Or some other number congruent to $1$ mod $4$?

Answer (score 1):

$1 = 105\cdot 1-4\cdot 26 = 105\cdot 1+(-4)\cdot 26$ tells us that the answer is $1$ (the multiplier of 105), which is the same as $5$, mod $4$.